# InfoPath form loading web service on load

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and Form Services. I have an InfoPath (IP) form which calls a web service. This web service is relative to the current server, actually it's a feature I created. I set the Data Connection in the IP form to not load on start. In the code behind I change the serviceurl to the current server's URL. It works great on my dev box, but when I move it to the staging server it errors, error below. It does however still run through my codebehind on my code and my data appears.

The following query failed: ListGroupUsers (User: DOMAIN\SPADMIN, Form Name: RequestForm, IP: , Connection Target: , Request: http://sp.domain.com/FCSWorkPagesLibrary/request-intake.aspx?SaveLocation=https://sp.domain.com/Request Forms, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:RequestForm:-myXSD-2010-09-10T15-05-49 Type: DataAdapterException, Exception Message: The remote name could not be resolved: 'bricweb1'
The remote name could not be resolved: 'bricweb1')

bricweb1 is my dev box.

Thanks,

Comment: So, are you trying to connect to the dev. box from your staging env? Or is the error exactly that?

Comment: i want the staging server to connect to itself, not the dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is looking at the dev box still for the data connection. My suggestion is to save as the source files for the form, then open the manifest.xsf with notepad. I would do a search for the dev box name and then replace it with the staging server name and then publish. If you are using a multi-server environment, you may want to consider a DNS entry of a server name using a load balanced IP address for the server name in order to keep the load equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want portable data connections in InfoPath forms, the proper way to do it is with Data Connection Libraries. Here are a couple of links on how to use them. They are easy, they work, and it seperates the physical location of your data services from your form providing a good layer of abstraction.

[How To: Create and Use a Data Connection Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772101.aspx)

[Manage Data Connection Files for InfoPath Forms Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621104.aspx)